# open browser, full screen, with on screen keyboard at startup, not closable

Tags: windows, vb.net, keyboard, fullscreen

I need that one of our computers, when it boots, automatically opens `Internet Explorer`. `IE` should be Full screen (without the border and the address bar.. totally full screen) and open a default URL (no problem on this, just set it as homepage). Then I would need that if a textbox inside this page gets focus then the on-screen keyboard should show up.

can this be achived with standard windows settings or do i have to write my own program with browser inside? if i write my own vb.net program, can the program be totally fullscreen (without the X to close and without seeing the task bar)

what we need to do is set up a sort of a internet station where random people can browse a given page without having a keyboard and without having the possibility to access the system.

thanks

Comment: Take a look at the kiosk mode... that should help you without vb.net.
I would lock the taskbar via group policy.
Also you have to disable the task manager

Comment: thanks, so far so good! now i would need the keyboard to show up.. is that possible? please add your next comment as answer so i can mark it as accepted. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is possible - but I have no idea how to achieve this. There will be a registry setting of some sort which SHOULD enable the keyboard. Sorry - I barely touched this areas :(